# clear interval not working with if else condition

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div class="box" style="margin-top:80px;margin-bottom:80px">

            <div class="back">

            <div class="container skills set" id="set">

                <span id="percent">100</span><span>%</span>

            </div>

            </div>

      <div ><span id="damage">2000</span><span>/2000</span></div>

        </div>
<button  onclick="cli()" >click me </button>
```

Above is the html and below is the js

```
    var health = parseInt(document.getElementById("damage").innerHTML);

        if(health > 0){

       var myInterval = setInterval(cli, 1000); 

    }

    else {

        clearInterval(myInterval);
console.log("sttoped");
    }

    

function cli(){

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() *1000)+1;

    console.log("running");

     var on=document.getElementById("percent");

    var content = document.getElementById("set");

 health = health - rand;

var calc = Math.floor((health/2000)*100);

document.getElementById("damage").innerHTML = Math.floor(health);

if(health < 0){

    document.getElementById("damage").innerHTML = 0;

    content.style.width = 0;

    on.innerHTML = "0";

}

 else{

    on.innerHTML = calc;

        content.style.width = `${calc}%`;

 

}

    }
```

I am trying to run the function per 1 sec only if the health is above 0 and stop the interval if it drops below 0, but it's not working and it's not showing any error on console, any help would be greatly helpful. Here is the codepen link for [live preview and test](https://codepen.io/gauntletww/pen/eYVdNyz).

Comment: your code is randomly formatted - perhaps that's why you cant fix the issue

Comment: that first if/else will run **exactly** once ... so either a interval begins, or a (non-existent) interval is stopped ... but there is no possibility, at all, that `clearInterval(myInterval)` will EVER run if `myInterval = setInterval(cli, 1000);` is executed ... since that test (the if) is run exactly once and only once